# Convert A function react component To a react class To Add ref attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component with a trigger Element, the trigger Element is A react component  like the following

```
const TriggerComponent = () => <div> trigger example </div>

<MyComponent  trigger={<TriggerComponent />} />
```

Inside the MyComponent class, I want to add a ref attribute to the trigger Element by cloneElement or creatElement API, of course, I can't add a ref attribute to a functional component according to react documentation. So my idea is to convert the function component to class?

lets me know if you have any idea on how can I implement this idea?

Comment: you want to get a `ref` from the `TriggerComponent` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to add ref to stateful component children is by creating a class Ref and inject your function component as a child like the following  :

```
class Ref extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}
componentDidMount() {
  const { innerRef } = this.props;
  if (innerRef) innerRef(findDOMNode(this));
}
render() {
  const { children } = this.props;
  return React.Children.only(children);
}
```

}

and we can add ref to function component.

```
const Trigger = ()=> <button> trigger </button>
const RefTrigger = () => <Ref innerRef={this.setRef}><Trigger/></Ref>
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can** pass a ref callback to a stateless component:

```
const TriggerComponent = ({ triggerRef }) => <div ref={triggerRef}> trigger example </div>
```

Running example:

```js
const TriggerComponent = ({ triggerRef }) => <div ref={triggerRef}> trigger example, click me </div>

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.trigger.addEventListener('click', () => { console.log('triggered') });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <TriggerComponent triggerRef={ref => { this.trigger = ref }} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Sagiv, the component is built for a simple lib, so  I think it's more useful if I don't add extra condition to the trigger prop